# Submit date selected on asp calendar to database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am working on a little individual project at the moment. I have created a table in a database which has a column that allows smalldatetime data type.

I have used Entity Framework to open a model in Visual Studio and in the web application have an asp calendar and a button to submit.

My question is: how would it be possible to save a date that is selected on the calendar by an onClick event on that submit button to the database model I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, you just have to bind the click event (whatever front-end technology you are using) and fill the logic in.

The most common scenario is to have a onclick binding on your front end that triggers a JS function that calls your backend (e.g. api/saveDateTime), POSTing a json (e.g.
 {  value: something }). Then in your backend you handle the request and store the data on the database as usual. That's it.

Don't know your level, btw have a look at:

- binding onclick events on JS
- creating ajax request with JS (I suggest to use at least jQuery)
- c# web api handle ajax requests (e.g. a POST)

Comment: My level in ajax is low but I will look over the topics you have just referred. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax method to call a function and pass the values.

Comment: Yea I am really newbie when it comes to ajax but I will definitely have a look at it! Thanks